# Can any experts tell me how can I close the upper line and the lower line of the table?

Tags: tables

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% define colors

%line space
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{plan}
    \begin{tabular} {|m{3cm}<{\centering}|m{3cm}<{\centering}|}
    \toprule
    \textbf{University} & \textbf{Country} \\
    \hline
    University of London & United Kingdom \\
    
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:Secondment plan}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

This is what I got. Can any experts tell me how can I close the upper line and the lower line? How to make the table look nicer?
[image]

Comment: Don't use `booktabs` – it adds vertical padding around its rules. If you want thicker horizontal lines, you can load `makecell` and use its `\Xhline{thickness}` or `\Xcline{thickness}` commands.

Comment: Or don't use vertical rules, they tend to look ugly anyway. (and if so, use `\midrule` instead of `\hline` under your head row)

Comment: If you actually want to use vertical rules with the rules of `booktabs` (`\toprule`, etc.), you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

Comment: Can you give me an complete example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: read the booktabs manual: the package code intentionally makes vertical rules unusable, and the manual is designed to make you feel guilty for suggesting ever having such a rule.

Answer (score 6):

Rules defined in the `booktabs` package are not intended to be used in table with vertical lines. Gapes, which are added to rules can be dealt with table packages `nicematrix` (as mentioned package author in his comment) as well package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{plan}
  \label{tab:Secondment plan}%
    \begin{tblr}{vlines,
                 colspec = {*{2}{Q[c, m, 30mm]}},
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}
                 }
    \toprule
University              &   Country         \\
    \hline
University of London    & United Kingdom    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you actually want to use vertical rules with the horizontal rules of booktabs (which is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`!), you can use `nicematrix`. Just load `nicematrix` and replace `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\usepackage{nicematrix}
% define colors

%line space
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{plan}
    \begin{NiceTabular} {|m{3cm}<{\centering}|m{3cm}<{\centering}|}
    \toprule
    \textbf{University} & \textbf{Country} \\
    \hline
    University of London & United Kingdom \\
    
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}%
  \label{tab:Secondment plan}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]